# vbscript to check if a window is open using wildcard

Tags: vbscript

I would like to check if a window is open using wildcard in vbscript. I was able to find the code below:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If oShell.AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad") Then
   WScript.Sleep 500
End If
```

But i would like to use a wildcard on the window title. I tried using * and % but it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
If oShell.AppActivate("*Notepad*") Then
```

Updates guys.. I was able to find a solution but it is still open if someone can simplify this. Thank you.

```
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks

isFound = False
For i = 1 to 5
    For Each Task in Tasks
      checkVal = 0
      If Task.Visible Then
        checkVal = inStr(UCase(Task.name), UCase("outlook"))
        If checkVal <> 0 Then
            isFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
      End If
    Next
    If isFound = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Next

Word.Quit
msgbox ("Is the Window Found? - " & isFound)
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a natively installed library you could use to obtain this. There are some libraries/wrappers out there to let you achieve this but you wont be able to achieve this from raw VBScript without obtaining/coding an additional library. You could try using TASKLIST with a shell execute stdout capture with something like tasklist /v | find /i "search string here"

Comment: Additionally... you could use a regex to capture the Window Title field from that tasklist output. (?:.*)(?:\d:\d\d:\d\d\s)(.*)

Comment: Hi Steve - i tried to find a solution using RegEx but luckily i was able to find some solution i updated my question above already.

By the way that's what i do i get all the names on the task list and loop on it to find the string that i'm looking for using inStr function.

Comment: Theres a much faster way than creating a word document.... see my answer below.

Comment: AppActivate already has an implied wildcard. `In determining which application to activate, the specified title is compared to the title string of each running application. If no exact match exists, any application whose title string begins with title is activated. If an application still cannot be found, any application whose title string ends with title is activated. If more than one instance of the application named by title exists, one instance is arbitrarily activated.`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method versus creating a word doc. That method requires a dependency of having office installed. This uses only native Windows libraries.

**First function: findwindowtitle**
Executes the Tasklist command to enumerate and filter down the list of titles. Then fires off the regex parser to match your string against the leftover values from tasklist.

**Second function: matchtitle** Then it proceeds to use convert your wildcard into a regular expression of the [a-zA-Z0-9.- ] which is alphanumeric including spaces. Kind of required for the wildcard and allowed characters for windows files to work.

```
MysearchString = "*Notepad"
processtitle = findwindowtitle(MysearchString)
wscript.echo "My search found window title: '" & processtitle & "'"
'do something with processtitle 


function findwindowtitle(srchstr)
    filtersrchstr = replace(srchstr, "*", "")
    strcommand = "tasklist /v | find /i """ & filtersrchstr & """"
    cmdout = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c """ & strcommand & " 2>&1 """).stdout.readall
    wscript.sleep 500
    findwindowtitle = matchtitle(srchstr, cmdout)
End Function

Function matchtitle(srchstr, input)
    matchtitle = false
    if instr(1, srchstr, "*", 1) <> 0 Then 
        filtersrchstr = replace(srchstr, "*", "")
        filterstrpatt = replace(srchstr, "*", "[a-zA-Z0-9\.- ]*")
    end if
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.MultiLine = True
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = "(?:.*)(?:\d\d?\d?:\d\d:\d\d\s)(\b" & filterstrpatt & "\b)"
    Set matches = regex.Execute(input)
    for m = 0 to matches.count - 1
        Set SubMatches = matches.item(m).SubMatches
        for i = 0 to (Submatches.count - 1)
            if instr(1, Submatches.item(i), filtersrchstr, 1) <> 0 then matchtitle = Submatches.item(i)
        Next
    Next
    if (matchtitle = false) then
        wscript.echo "Could not find process with title matching, '" & srchstr & "'"
        wscript.quit
    end if
End Function
```